# "sudo crontab -e" does not show the cron job which I gave

Tags: ubuntu, cron

Am using Ubuntu14.04. Server Backup will take place every week. But will this affect the crontab? Because "sudo crontab -e" does not contain the cron job which I gave. Please help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: "The cron job that you gave"? How did you give tho cronjob?

Comment: Crystal ball guess: `crontab -e` shows your personal crontab. the personal crontab, even for the root user, is unrelated to the system crontab in `/etc/crontab`, `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/cron.weekly` and friends.

Comment: Try `sudo crontab -u <user> -e` instead or were you trying to set-up a system crontab?

Comment: @Kusalananda : I used this command "crontab -e"

Comment: @Tigger This works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every user has their individual crontab. This includes the root user.

When you add a cronjob with `crontab -e`, you add it into the list of jobs for the *current user*.

This means that with `sudo crontab -e`, you will be editing the list of cron jobs for the root user.

To edit the crontab for a specific user, use `sudo crontab -e -u username`, or log in as that user and use `crontab -e`.